# Input field id is not accessible in jquery when the id is the mixture of English and Arabic

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using the dynamic method where the name and id of input the element will be in different languages but I am facing this issue. Like if the input id of the element is a mixture of English and Arabic. Its value is not accessible in jquery.

HTML Code

`<input type="text" name="relation_كرتون|CARTON"  id="relation_كرتون|CARTON" class="form-control" required />` (not accessible in jquery)

`<input type="text" name="relation_CARTON" id="relation_CARTON" class="form-control" required />` (accessible in jquery)

Javascript Code

`var getId = $("#relation_كرتون|CARTON").val();`
(not accessible here)

`var getId = $("#relation_CARTON").val();`
(accessible here)

It gives me the error relation_كرتون|CARTON is undefined. input element id is not accessible.
But when the element id is in English its value is accessible. Please help.

Comment: Works fine when you follow [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), I'd stick to plain English ids, though.

Comment: Your code is same for (not accessible here) and (accessible here). Can you explain more, where it is accessible and where it is not?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. The code is the same but the input ids are different.

Comment: It should really just work. Is your site using a different encoding than UTF-8? Is the encoding correctly declared?

Comment: Typo: The `name` is not the `id` (also `|` is a special character that needs escaping, but that wouldn't matter if you used the IDs which don't contain that character)

Comment: @Quentin This is not a name I knew but it's client work. These id coming from JSON code and we don't have any id here. That why we can use this as id we are making very complex logic according to id.

Comment: @Quentin this is not the solution.

Comment: You have `name="relation_كرتون|CARTON" id="test_امتحان"` and `"#relation_كرتون|CARTON"` which is an ID selector. The `id` is `test_امتحان`. The `name` is `relation_كرتون|CARTON"`. You're using the value from the *wrong attribute* in your selector.

Comment: Can you please revert your changes?

Comment: My changes are literally a cut/paste of the code you provided into a live demo plus the addition to jQuery. You're quite capable of reverting that yourself. I don't recommend doing so. Live demos are useful. The save time for people trying to help you.

Comment: Well, your edit has changed the IDs to different values from when I last looked at the question. My point about having to escape `|` stands. Also your code would still be better as a live demo.

Comment: Sure, I will add sandbox link in my code. THanks

Comment: You can have a string that is a valid HTML5 ID, yet is not a valid selector.  As @Quentin commented, special characters like | must be escaped when used in a selector.  This code causes both jQuery and plain JS to fail with "invalid selector".  Remove or escape the | bar and the Arabic in the ID causes no problem.

Comment: jQuery 3.0 added https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/, so you can use that if you need to work around the issue. In previous versions, you'll probably have to write a bit of code to perform the escaping of the special characters yourself.

Answer (score -1):

go to notepad, open your jQuery script and click 'Save as' and then make sure encoding is 'UTF-8'

Comment: I already added it. But nothing happened.

Comment: You must use arabic in your ids ?

Answer (score -1):

This escape sign | is giving the issue. But when I use the below code. It works fine with the escape sign too.

`document.getElementById("relation_كرتون|CARTON").value`

Comment: With `document.getElementById` you are not using CSS selectors in the first place.

Comment: I don't need css selector in the above code. I just want to get the input field value which has escape char in javascript.

Comment: That was in reference to your not understanding why this behaves differently (_"But when I use the below code. It works fine with the escape sign too."_) And since this is not even an answer to the question that was asked here, you should not have posted it as such to begin with. _Edit_ your question, if you think you have useful information to add.

Comment: Please read my question and then test the above scenario. I have asked that I can't access the input field value in the script section and it gives me an error whenever I used jquery for getting value from id i.e  $("#relation_كرتون|CARTON").val(); but when I used document.getElementById("relation_كرتون|CARTON").value; this in script section. It accessible. So, what wrong about the question.